# Почему некорректно отображаются SVG на сайте?

Tags: svg, браузер

Добавляю на сайт svg через php echo file_get_contents(..path..file...) если добавляю 1-2 svg, то все норм, но стоит добавить больше, то во-первых на некоторых изображениях какого-то фига меняется цвет заливки, во-вторых некоторые элементы одного SVG файла не отображаются.

Например, цвет заливки какого-то элемента был синий, стал коричневый, в другом SVG файле есть человек и планета, так вот планета исчезает, остается только человек.

В коде файла не нашел img, везде Image (где-то в инете читал что должно быть именно Image, а не img) + нашел такой кусок "xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA......" - откуда здесь png? Хотя изображение в целом масштабируется без косяков. Все видно четко при любом его размере.

Что может быть? Косячный свг или что ?

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1160 1016" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
<path d="M306 802V80H538.45C602.221 80 659.549 94.5458 710.434 123.637C761.318 152.398 800.969 193.226 829.385 246.12C858.131 298.683 872.67 357.692 873 423.148V456.372C873 522.489 858.957 581.83 830.872 634.393C803.116 686.625 763.796 727.618 712.912 757.371C662.358 786.793 605.856 801.669 543.406 802H306ZM479.966 214.383V668.113H540.433C590.326 668.113 628.655 650.426 655.419 615.054C682.183 579.35 695.565 526.457 695.565 456.372V425.132C695.565 355.378 682.183 302.815 655.419 267.442C628.655 232.07 589.665 214.383 538.45 214.383H479.966Z" fill="white"/>
</g>
<mask id="mask0" mask-type="alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="25" width="1339" height="1335">
<path d="M362.323 346.752C162.445 524.45 137.95 823.207 307.612 1014.04C477.273 1204.88 776.843 1215.53 976.721 1037.83C1176.6 860.137 1201.09 561.38 1031.43 370.542C861.771 179.705 562.2 169.053 362.323 346.752Z" fill="url(#paint0_radial)"/>
</mask>
....
</svg>
```

Comment: без кода мало что можно сказать

Comment: @StrangerintheQ код слишком большой для выкладывания здесь

Comment: если пересекаются стили или идентификаторы - будут ошибки, вставляйте svg как картинки...